# Only one radio button value is inserted in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a dynamic radio button that inserts a list of student attendance data
but only one student data is inserted. What am I doing wrong

When only the first student gets inserted. The rest of the students do not get inserted into the database

```
<div class="table">

    <table class="table table-sm table-bordered mx-auto">
        <tr>
            <th>Student Name</th>
            <th>Attendence Status</th>
        </tr>
        <tbody>

        <?php
        while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($select)) {
        $student_id=$row['student_id'];
        $student_name=$row['student_lastname'].' '.$row['student_midname'].' '.$row['student_firstname'];
        $link='student_images/'.$row['student_img'];

        ?>
        <tr>
            <td class="px-md-2" ><?php echo '<img src="'.$link.'" class="profile-user-img img-fluid img-circle" alt="Student Picture"  />'  ?>
                <p class="profile-username lead"><?php echo $student_name; ?></p>
                <p class="text-muted "><?php echo "Date:".' '.date("d/m/Y");   ?></p>
            </td>
            <td class="mx-auto" style="width: 40%;">
                <div class="radio icheck-square">
                    <input type="radio" value="1" id="state" name="<?php echo $student_id; ?>" />
                    <label for="present">Present</label>
                </div>
                <div class="radio icheck-square">
                    <input type="radio" value="0"  id="state" name="<?php echo $student_id; ?>" />
                    <label for="absent">Absent</label>
                </div></td>

        </tr>
        <input type="hidden" name="student_id" id="student_id" value="<?php echo $student_id ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="date" id="date" value="<?php echo date("Y/m/d");   ?>">
        <?php
        }

        ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="AddOnly();">Add Attendance Only</button>
            or
            <button class="btn btn-info" onclick="AddSend();">Add Attendance & Alert Parents</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</div>
```

The PHP code is that processes the data is below

```
$state=$_POST['state'],
$student_id=$_POST['student_id'];
$date=$_POST['date'];

$insert=mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO `aza_attendance`(`attendance_id`, `student_id`, `atten_date`, `state`) VALUES (NULL, '$student_id', '$date', '$state')") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
    if ($insert) {

        if ($state==1) {
            echo $student_id. 'was at school on'.' '.$date;
        }else if($state==0){
            echo $student_id. 'was at <strong>NOT</strong> school on'.' '.$date;
        }


    }
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

i think is not good to use a variable in name like you use here name="" i think this is better just put them in one div

```
<div class="radio icheck-square">
                    <input type="radio" value="1" id="state" name="state" />
                    <label for="present">Present</label>

                    <input type="radio" value="0"  id="state" name="state" />
                    <label for="absent">Absent</label>
                </div>
```